# Cant login to Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia drivers installed and Gnome3

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 fresh on my Hard Drive. It would always get stuck before Login Screen (only a purple screen). With the boot option `nouveau.modeset=0` in GRUB i could boot Ubuntu normally and login (everything fine).

When i install the NVIDIA drivers i'll get stuck before login screen again.

I'm using Gnome3 window manager. I tried lightdm and could login but i didnt see any windows, taskbar etc.

My GPU is GTX970 btw.